# How to ensure that the built-in audio (laptop speakers) profile is set to off at startup?

Tags: sound, speakers, pavucontrol

#### Background

I have a laptop computer that i run XUbuntu 22.04 on. Sometimes i use the built-in speakers, and often i use bluetooth headphones (but not both at the same time)

#### Problem

After startup of my laptop it uses the configuration i had last activated, which sometimes results in audio played being sent to the speakers, so everyone in the room can hear it (for example i might be in a library or a public place)

#### Question

**How can i make sure that the audio for the built-in speakers is turned off at startup?** (For example by automatically setting the "Built-in Audio" profile to "Off" at startup of my laptop computer)

#### What i do now

To avoid this problem what i do now is that each time i restart my laptop in a public place i try to remember to:

1. open pavucontrol,
2. go to the "Configuration" tab,
3. look at the "Profile" under "Built-in Audio",
4. and turn it "Off" (if not already set to "Off")

[image: pavucontrol]

Comment: Interestingly, my xubuntu maintains separate volume levels for speakers and headphones (albeit mine are wired), so once muted, the speakers never get enabled automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine the Sound Card's Index:

```bash
pacmd list-cards
```

One-time command to test:

```bash
pactl set-card-profile <cardindex> off
```

Once you've confirmed the above command works, you can put this in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to set on every startup automatically:

```
set-card-profile <cardindex> off
```